# What's the convention to define backbone models class properties/fields

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to define which properties a class has. We use backbone for OOP. I've read that backbone model gets its properties when initialized, and only methods are defined for the class using `extend`. But I think that having explicitly defined class fields adds to readability. Is there some convention on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend):

> **extend** `Backbone.Model.extend(properties, [classProperties])`
>   [...] as well as optional **classProperties** to be attached directly to the constructor function.

Similarly for [collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-extend), [routers](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-extend), and [views](http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend).

To define a class method on a model:

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // instances methods and properties go here...
}, {
    some_class_method: function() { ... }
});

M.some_class_method(); // Then this will work.
```

Answer (score 0):

Backbone models hold data in the `attributes` key so

```
model = new Backbone.Model({foo:'bar'});
model.attributes.foo === 'bar';
```

and you should access data with `model.get()` `model.set()` which will manage events firing.

you can also hook into Backbone models creations using `initilize` method or by rewriting `constructor` (you may look at MarionetteJS views for an inspiration).